# Rest api URI design for messages monitoring system

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm working on the monitoring system dealing with messages. Messages processing pipeline is the following:
new -> in process -> processed -> removed (history)

The system must be able to:

- request all messages and by the unique identifier
- modify them (I mean mark as processed, mark as removed, etc)
- search using message field filters (for example, search by message
  owner)

I cannot design the RESTful URIs containing nouns, not the verbs for this. It is difficult for me to identify the correct resources in this system.

The easiest way was to go with URIs like

```
host/messages/new
host/messages/processing
host/messages/processed
host/messages/removed
```

but it is not REST, because
- this is still the same messages but with different field values, they are not new entities
- I used verbs for identifying states, not the resources

So the question is how to apply the REST design here?
I can hardly imagine the REST design for the system dealing with object state monitoring.

I would be thankful for your thoughts and advice on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

To start with, RESTful systems shouldn't put to much effort in the design of URIs, instead they should focus on the creation of media-types and use relation names for URIs to give clients the possibility to lookup its meaning in the media-type. The client itself does not validate or interpret URIs and hence does not really care how an URI looks like, it will just invoke the URI based on the relation name according to the semantics outlined in the media-type.

This has the advantage of binding a resource to a relation name rather than to the concrete URI. If the server changes the location of the resource a client using the relation name rather than the URI itself will still be able to process the request regardless of the location the URI is pointing to.

For your concrete example you have a message resource and some state belonging to that resource. How you design this relation is up to you. If you want the actual payload of the message untouched you can put the state information either in the header, which are basically metadata of the document returned, or define them in a subresource of the respective message. You can also use (or define your own) media-type that supports embedded resources similar to [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) which allows to embed additional data belonging to a certain resource.

A HAL-like represent for a message including its current state may look like the example below. Note however, that this representation is not based on an actual media-type nor is it complete. It should just visualize the concepts you can use in your approach.

```json
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/messages/1234",
            "title": "Get the latest version of this message"
        },
        "states": {
            "href": "/api/messages/1234/states",
            "title": "List states the message has been in in chronological order"
        },
        "find": {
            "href": "/api/messages{?id,sender,receiver,state}",
            "templated": true,
            "title": "Find messages"
        },
        "markAsProcessed": {
            "href": "/api/messages/1234/states",
            "title": "Mark message as processed",
            "type": "application/vnd.your-comp.message-state-update+hal+json"
        },
        ...
    },
    "sender": "User1",
    "receiver": "User2",
    ...
    "_embedded": {
        "current_status": {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "/api/messages/1234/states/new"
                }
            }
            "type": "new",
            "timestamp": "2017-10-21'T'22:25:00Z",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In HTML data to send to a server is usually entered in a formular (`<form>...</form>`). HAL does not define such a construct explicitly. On extending your media type this can now either define a counterpart to HTML forms within your media type or define a ruleset how a client should process certain relation names.

In this simple example the client will have to deduct how to process a certain link-relation like `markAsProcessed` based on the media-type the data was exchanged for. It may define that a request invoking the `markAsProcessed` link relation should send a `PUT` request containing the latest state information for the given message to the server. In this case it is explicitly listed that a request issued to the server should be in a representation compatible with media-type `application/vnd.your-comp.message-state-update+hal+json` which defines the actual syntax and semantic of the payload that the server will expect.

[HAL (draft version 08)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-5.3) provides a couple other fields you can use inside link-relation names. If this are insufficient to your needs you have to extend the media type by adding new fields for links that specifies that i.e. `PUT`, `PATCH` or `POST` should be used though. This has also to be defined within a new or extended media-type and probably made available to other clients as well by [registering it with IANA](https://www.iana.org/form/media-types) in order to allow other vendors to implement this media-type into their frameworks and thus allow other clients to make use of this media type as well.

Before creating a new media-type, however, you should [check the registered media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) if something similar is already available which you can use or extend further.

Note that his is just a suggestion. As REST is not a protocol but just an architectural style, which if followed correctly allows clients in a distributed system to get decoupled from server APIs. If you maintain your own clients for your Web API, you can of course follow your own approch, though you should probably remarked your service to a simple Web API and avoid the "marketing term" REST further.

Comment: Would be nice if the downvoter could explain his reasoning behind the downvote in order to improve the answer as none of the information outlined here is wrong to my knowledge but is in accordance with the REST idea (and not with the marketing term used for Web APIs)